# Scheme : Make operations on a list without changing its copy?

Tags: list, scheme

I have a helper to copy a list :

```
(define (list-copy list)
  (if (null? list)
      '()
      (cons (car list) (list-copy (cdr list)))))
```

Then,

```
(define (multList lst1 lst2)
  (define lstCopy2 (list-copy lst2))  
  (cond ((null? lst1) ())
        ((eq? (length lst1) (length lst2)) (cons (* (car lst1) (car lst2)) (multList (cdr lst1) (cdr lst2)))) 
        ((> (length lst1) (length lst2))
         (if (null? lst2) lstCopy2
         (cons (* (car lst1) (car lst2)) (multList (cdr lst1) (cdr lst2)))))
        (else '())))
```

I'm trying to copy lst2 into lstCopy2 and then I would like lstCopy2 to stay intact when I'm working on lst2 in order to call lst2 (with the help of lstCopy2) as it was at first.
In my 3rd cond (when lenght lst1 > lenght lst2) when lst2 = () I would like to continue the process until lst1 is ().

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you have an editor with parenthesis matching, if so turn it on, if not get one. Trailing out the parenthesis on separate lines is annoying. You should rely on white space to show code structure and us the parenthesis matcher to make sure parenthesis match the white space.

Comment: Also if you are recurring on lists and are calling length on that list every time, it's likely the code is more convoluted then necessary as the length of the list should become apparent as you cdr down it. It also turn a nice procedure whose time is proportional to the size of the input lists, to a procedure whose time is proportional the the square of the size of the input lists. Unlike vectors, finding the length of the linked list is linear time process instead of a constant time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about this in a very odd way. The standard way to do this is the define an inner function. Usually you inner function and then call it.

The way you were doing it you were making a copy of lst2 every time you called multList, which is not what i think you want.

But I don't see where you actually reference the original 2nd list so I don't see the reason behing what you want to do.

```
(define (multList oL1 oL2)
  (define (helper lst1 lst2)
     (cond ((null? lst1) '())   
           ((null? lst2) (helper lst1 oL2))
           (else
            (cons (* (car lst1) (car lst2)) 
                  (helper (cdr lst1) (cdr lst2))))))
  (helper oL1 oL2))

(multlist '(9 2 4) '(1 2))

;Value 14: (9 4 4)

(multlist '(1 2) '(9 2 4))

;Value 15: (9 4)
```

See what I mean about not really being a proper multiplication? (multist a b) is not always the same as (multlist b a).

Comment: I don't want the process to stop when lst2 came to () but it restart at the beggining of lst2 until lst1 is ()

Comment: I'm trying to understand your code :) so what would I have to change in order to get :
(multlist '(1 2) '(9 2 4)) ===> (9 4 4)
As you have said before to be a proper multiplication (multlist a b) = (multlist b a)

Comment: If you want it be be the same either was you call it, you should probably change (helper oL1 0L2) to (let ((shorter ..) (longer ...)) (helper longer shorter)) filling the the .. as aporpriate. and change the oL2 reference in the second case of the helper cond to shorter.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see your copy is not used. In addition, none of the procedure mutates anything so `(equal? lst2 lstCopy2)` will always be `#t` for every recursion / element of the list.

If `lst1` is shorter than `lst2` or you've reached the end of the list you will get an error since `()` is an illegal expression. perhaps you meant `'()`?

This could have been written a lot easier:

```
(require srfi/1)

(define (multList lst1 lst2)
  (define (aux lst1 lst2)
    (if (null? lst2)
        '()
        (cons (* (car lst1) 
                 (car lst2)) 
              (aux (cdr lst1) (cdr lst2)))))
  (aux (apply circular-list lst1) lst2))

(multList '(1 -1) '(1 2 3 4 5 6)) ; ==> (1 -2 3 -4 5 -6)

;; with srfi-1-version of map we can use it to make the code shorter
(define (multList lst1 lst2)
  (map * (apply circular-list lst1) lst2))
```

Comment: I'm only working for now on the case length lst1 > length lst2 since when length lst1 = length lst2 its working well.

Comment: (multList '(9 2 4) '(1 2))
what's your function is doing ===> (9 4)
what I need is ===> (9 4 9)

Comment: @Dovakin940 Where's that last 9 comming from? That would also make it not a true muliplication as it doesn't preserve the property a*b = b*a.

Comment: @Dovakin940 I'm not quite following. How did it mount to `9` in the last iteration when one of the lists were `'()` and you have `4`?

Comment: My bad I made a mistake
that's what I want :
(multList '(9 2 4) '(1 2)) ==> (9 4 4)

Comment: @Dovakin940 Rewritten my procedure to append the rest of the longer list.

Comment: (multList '(1 -2) '(1 1 1 1)) results (1 -2 1 1) 
instead of (1 -2 1 -2)

Comment: @Dovakin940 I've updated my answer so you have two more alternative approaches. Wor's is good though.